# Align 3 elements in css

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements which I want to align in my html file. I have attached a sample image, the first image just has a left margin and is vertically centered. the middle element is vertically and horizontally centered and the third element has right margin and is vertically centered.
[image]
I can independently align elements horizontally and vertically with below code :

```
#element{
    height : 40%;
    position : relative;
    left : 50%;
    top : 50%;
    transform : translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

but when it comes to align elements along each other they don't place correctly.
I'll appreciate if you can help me with this.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with below code :

```
<header id="header">
    <div id="element1Container">
        <img id="element1" src="http://globalapk.com/uploads/posts/2014-06/1402152414_unnamed.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="element2Container">
        <img id="element2"     src="http://globalapk.com/uploads/posts/2014-06/1402152414_unnamed.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="element3Container">
        <img id="element3" src="http://globalapk.com/uploads/posts/2014-06/1402152414_unnamed.png"/>
    </div>
</header>
```

and here's the css:

```
#header{
    background:#2b2b2b;
  height : 8.5%;
    width : 100%;
    position : absolute;
}
#header #element1Container{
    position : relative;
    height : 100%;
    width : 25%;
    float : left;
}
#header #element1Container img{
    height : 65%;
    top : 50%;
    position : relative;
    float : left;
    margin-left : 4%;
    transform : translate(0,-50%);
}
#header #element2Container{
    position : relative;
    float : left;
    height : 100%;
    width : 50%;    
}
#header #element2Container img{
    height : 40%;
    position : relative;
    left : 50%;
    top : 50%;
    transform : translate(-50%,-50%);
}
#header #element3Container{
    position : relative;
    float : right;
    height : 100%;
    width : 25%;
}
#header #element3Container img{
    height : 65%;
    top : 50%;
    position : relative;
    float : right;
    margin-right : 4%;
    transform : translate(0,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
.left_item {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}
.right_item {
  float: right;
  width: 10%;
}
.center_item {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want to use width , I only want to use height:x% and let the width to be adjusted by ratio, an how about positioning center vertically?

Comment: I think you can position the center vertically using margin: 0 auto;

Comment: No it didn't do anything